# How do I create tables in VS 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008

I am running VS 2008 Standard and SQL Server Express. I created the tables in the Database Designer (creating and xsd), and created the database. How do I get the tables from the Database Designer into the database? Also, is there some documentation available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original flow would've been to:

1. use Server Explorer in Visual Studio to create tables, views and stored procs.
2. Create the .xsd model 'from database' instead of by hand.

The xsd really is the model for how the data is shaped in the application, rather than in storage at the database.

Unsure if there is a way to explicitly export/create SQL scripts from your .xsd designer. If it was enough of a time-saver, you could:

- create a new TSQL query, copy paste the XSD into a `varchar(max)` variable.
- use [OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx) to get a set of the names of the tables & their columns.
- create SQL statements for `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: OK, I see. That's why I couldn't find a good answer by searching.

Thanks!